# Thread safety of StringBuilder class

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, stringbuilder

```
class Test {
    public string GetData() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("aassffss");
        sb.Append("bbhhhhh");
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
// calling from multithreads,as below, 
// from each thread i will create new 
// instance and call method.

Test t = new Test(); 
t.GetData();
```

As per the MSDN. any instance member of `StringBuilder` class is not thread safe.
so I believe this is not thread safe. Am I correct?

Comment: There's no sharing here so it is thread safe.

Comment: If two threads access your `Test.GetData()` method will always return a new instance to every caller. Though even that would be thread safe. But a call to any member of the `StringBuilder` itself may be interleaved by several threads

Comment: But i am not getting what MSDN says. "any instance member of String-builder class is not thread safe". So since we don't knw the internal implementation of stringbuiler class. let's say it has an static member. then this is not thread safe. am i right

Comment: @FatalError Static members of .net framework classes are usualy thread safe if necessary. Instance members are not, because if you are not sharing variable among threads there is no need for additional thread safety code at all. Maybe there is exceptions for this rule, but I haven't seen them yet.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Sry about your lost changes by my override. But my edit wasn't rejected, AFAIK. At least i can't see any changes done by me before on the question.

Comment: @Atomosk But my qz is we dont know the internal behavior of String-builder class. what happens if it has a static instance member. then it will be shared, even i have two different objects.

Comment: @FatalError I'll just repeat myself. Static members of .net framework classes are usualy thread safe if necessary.

Comment: @Atomosk i meant a static variable

Comment: @FatalError and by members, I meant classes, methods, fields, properties etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code is thread safe because no instances are shared between threads.

You would encounter a problem if you had a single instance shared between multiple threads. Then, if you had multiple instance method calls from different threads, on the same instance, the code would be unsafe.

Comment: Thanks. But i am  not getting what MSDN says. "any instance member of String-builder class is not thread safe".  So since we don't knw the internal implementation of stringbuiler class. let's say it has an static member. then this is not thread safe. am i right

Comment: @FatalError you're looking at the `GetData()` method and seem to think: when that method is executed from different threads, they access the same instance. But they don't. Every time you calls this method, an _new instance_ gets created. So no instances of StringBuilder are shared between threads, like David explains.

Comment: What it means is that calling instance methods on the **same instance** from different threads is unsafe.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sorry i may be still not getting what you were saying. If there is a static instance member inside string builder class and then there is only one static member in that appdomain. so it can be shared in two stringbuilder object in two threads.this makes above code not thread safe.

Comment: The issue here is basically a data race when two threads modify the same data. Are you familiar with that issue?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan pls. check my above comment. Also i have updated my qz above.

Comment: The answer remains the same. You are not sharing instances. Each thread has different instances.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan so you mean, if i create a new instance from any object from every separate thread . it will always thread safe.

Comment: Essentially yes. It is possible for classes to be written that share data between instances but that is bad design. For this class, StringBuilder, your statement in that comment is true.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan why you are saying it is bad. because even to method synchronization also we are using the same Technic and also to create singleton, we use static member which shares status between all other instances. The reason of my argument is that i want to know if MSDN says it is not thread safe and also we cannot see the actual implementation , i believe we always need to synchronize access to that object. even creating a instance who knows what is happening inside.

Comment: I don't understand that comment. Unless stated otherwise you should assume the calling instance methods on different instances is safe.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have two threads t0 and t1. Both use a shared instance of `StringBuilder sb`. Each thread runs the following corresponding methods `T0` `T1` :

```
public void T0()
{
    sb.Append("0");
    sb.Append("0");
}

public void T1()
{
    sb.Append("1");
    sb.Append("1");
}
```

Then you might get the following output on `sb.ToString()`

```
0011
0101
0110
1010
1100
```

So any of the above combinations is a thinkable result for the `ToString` method when using two threads calling an unsynchronized shared variable. In this case the shared variable is the `sb` instance where the problem lies inside of the class. Internally some buffer will be filled by calling the `Append` method on that instance. That buffer variable is the variable which is shared effectively.

Back to your question: Your code is thread safe as long as you don't share the instance with other threads and call methods such which share variables. If shared you need to synchronize calls to it yourself. Then consider implementing a synchronized wrapper.

Comment: You might also get a crash, or data might be lost, because MSDN says "any instance of StringBuilder is not thread safe", so it's invalid to call the same instance simultaneously from two threads.